# Barley Miso substitute?

Tags: substitutions, japanese-cuisine

I have a recipe that calls for barley miso. I don't find barley miso in the store but they do have about five other types. Can I substitute another one? which one? 
thanks

Comment: What type of food are you cooking?  With that information we might be able to give you a better answer for your specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

Miso is (usually) just a flavouring agent, so you almost certainly can substitute *any* other type of miso.  The flavour will of course be slightly different, but it is not going to ruin the recipe.

Barley miso that has been fermented for a long time is quite dark with a very strong flavour, so you may want to increase the amount of white miso or other miso to taste.

Comment: recipe is of a soup that uses wine and miso for most of it's flavor (from Friendly Foods by Ron Pickarski)